# Pitch detection using TarsosDSP

Tags: android, detection, pitch

I am trying to make a application using android studio. The application I'm going to make is a game using our voice. It works like this. If, I sing any Do( or near Do, C# for example) my car moves right and moves left if I sing Re(or maybe near Re). The point is my app first needs to recognize the sound I am making. After that, if my sound is in the range of [Do to Do#], it recognizes it as a Do and moves right. 
I recently found an library "TarsosDSP" that can help my work. I used an example that is on [link](https://medium.com/@juniorbump/pitch-detection-in-android-using-tarsosdsp-a2dd4a3f04e9), to figure out how it works. My code is right below

```
package sogangee.sibal3;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import be.tarsos.dsp.AudioDispatcher;
import be.tarsos.dsp.AudioEvent;
import be.tarsos.dsp.AudioProcessor;
import be.tarsos.dsp.io.android.AudioDispatcherFactory;
import be.tarsos.dsp.pitch.PitchDetectionHandler;
import be.tarsos.dsp.pitch.PitchDetectionResult;
import be.tarsos.dsp.pitch.PitchProcessor;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

AudioDispatcher dispatcher =
        AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(22050,1024,0);
TextView pitchText;
TextView noteText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pitchText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pitchText);
    noteText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noteText);

    PitchDetectionHandler pdh = new PitchDetectionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handlePitch(PitchDetectionResult res, AudioEvent e){
            final float pitchInHz = res.getPitch();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    processPitch(pitchInHz);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    AudioProcessor pitchProcessor = new PitchProcessor(PitchProcessor.PitchEstimationAlgorithm.FFT_YIN, 22050, 1024, pdh);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(pitchProcessor);
}

public void processPitch(float pitchInHz) {

    pitchText.setText("" + pitchInHz);

    if(pitchInHz >= 110 && pitchInHz < 123.47) {
        //A
        noteText.setText("A");
    }
    else if(pitchInHz >= 123.47 && pitchInHz < 130.81) {
        //B
        noteText.setText("B");
    }
    else if(pitchInHz >= 130.81 && pitchInHz < 146.83) {
        //C
        noteText.setText("C");
    }
    else if(pitchInHz >= 146.83 && pitchInHz < 164.81) {
        //D
        noteText.setText("D");
    }
    else if(pitchInHz >= 164.81 && pitchInHz <= 174.61) {
        //E
        noteText.setText("E");
    }
    else if(pitchInHz >= 174.61 && pitchInHz < 185) {
        //F
        noteText.setText("F");
    }
    else if(pitchInHz >= 185 && pitchInHz < 196) {
        //G
        noteText.setText("G");
    }
}
```

I am using AP 21: Android 5.0 (Lollipop) and my Emulator is NEXUS 6 API 24
I also added this word below in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO">
```

But I have errors like below

> `12-04 14:28:16.598 3448-3448/sogangee.sibal3 E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger 
>       could not create record track, status: -1
>       12-04 14:28:16.602 3448-3448/sogangee.sibal3 E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error 
>       creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status 
>       -1.
>       12-04 14:28:16.603 3448-3448/sogangee.sibal3 
>       E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native 
>       AudioRecord object.
>       12-04 14:28:16.606 3448-3448/sogangee.sibal3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                      Process: sogangee.sibal3, PID: 3448
>                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{sogangee.sibal3/sogangee.sibal3.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
>                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
>                                                                      at android.media.AudioRecord.startRecording(AudioRecord.java:976)
>                                                                      at be.tarsos.dsp.io.android.AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at sogangee.sibal3.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:20)
>                                                                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
>                                                                              at 
>       com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)`

How can I fix this problem?? I also have to use at least android 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(22050,1024,0);
```

Should not be called statically. So try calling it **in** `onCreate` or **after** `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 2):

In the virtual device check the app permissions. For whatever reason putting "uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"" doesn't always work.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens because on API v23+ you need to grant permission at the runtime not only by adding the permissions in the manifest file.
So to fix this error
"startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord."
You need to check Audio Record permission is granted at app start-up before firing any code relating to the Audio Record permission